# Ubuntu 15.10 Wifi device is not ready after updating kernel to 4.2.0-35

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10

I have Ubuntu 15.10. When I first installed it I've had some problems with wi-fi, and had to manually download and copy the firmware drivers, and that solved the problem. Yesterday there was some update. I've shutdown system yesterday after updating, and when I turned it on today there is no wifi. It just shows "device not ready".

Some additional info:

iwconfig

```
wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig

```
enp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:60:0c:f4:7d:a7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.33  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e60:cff:fef4:7da7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4152929 (4.1 MB)  TX bytes:787121 (787.1 KB)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
           RX packets:1567 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:1567 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:163215 (163.2 KB)  TX bytes:163215 (163.2 KB)
```

rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

If I remember correctly, phy0 Wireless was soft blocked, but I did rfkill unblock all.

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0807]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

I've tried

```
sudo ifconfig wlp7s0 up
```

responds with SIOCSIFFLAGS: Resource temporarily unavailable

I've tried many things that I've found on google, and none of them helped. Any idea how to revert things to how they were yesterday?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution. I've checked the updates (using software center), and there was a kernel update.

I've restarted the system and used old kernel (version from yesterday), and everything works perfect now. It seems that this wifi card is having some problems with some versions of linux.

Comment: What was the old and the new kernel version?

Comment: It is not working on 4.2.0-35
Everything is fine on 4.2.0-34
I'm going to update the question.

Comment: Maybe you have installed some drivers manually? It is normal that after a kernel update they do not work. But you do not need additional drivers for kernel 4.2.

Comment: Yes, I've been installing some of them manually. 

And the wi-fi wasn't working without it, and I didn't found any better solution.

These are the ones I've installed.
https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware

I've thought that they may be not working on new kernel, but I couldn't fix this problem.

Comment: Did you install any kernel modules or just firmware?

Comment: Just the firmware.

Comment: Then it is a real bug. It is better to report it to launchpad.

Comment: Ok, I will do so after I get back home.  Can you guide me what should I attach to my report? Never did that before.

Comment: You need to boot with the problem kernel, connect to internet by some other means and run in terminal `ubuntu-bug linux`. Everything else will be collected automatically.